# Ars gratia artis

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, grammar-identification, motto, translation-explanation

I would like to know the meaning of the following Latin expression, as well as a grammatical analysis of the individual words in this context:

> ARS GRATIA ARTIS

as it appears in the following logo of a lion with a "wreath" with the script on it for the company MGM (Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer):

[image: MGM Logo]

As mentioned in a comment, below, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_for_art%27s_sake?wprov=sfla1) states that ARS GRATIA ARTIS stands for "Art for Art's Sake", but it does not explain what each of the three words mean, their declension, and any other grammar details. Can someone please provide this in an answer?

Comment: It's explained on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_for_art%27s_sake

Comment: Can you please provide a word per word translation in an answer. I have no clue about Latin declensions. Thanks.

Comment: Please try by yourself! You can use [collatinus](http://outils.biblissima.fr/fr/collatinus-web/): copy paste your text in the section `Traiter un texte latin`, choose the `langue cible` and click on `Analyser`.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't give me any result, just says "Erreur", not even sure if I'm looking in the right place. Any ideas what I've five wrong, I posted the text five and pushed the button, the page related and the text disappeared.

Comment: @JackMaddington Try with the English version of the website: http://outils.biblissima.fr/en/collatinus-web/index.php ? (Sorry I gave you the French version). The text is displayed below the boxes.
--- --- 
By the way, I give you an hand: *ars* and *artis* are the same noun. *Gratia* followed by the gen. has the meaning of *in favor of, on account of, for the sake of*.

Comment: Thank you. You might want to make that Ann answer. Thanks.

Comment: So, the Latin "Ars Gratis Artis", MGM's motto, means, "For the sake of Art". Right?

Comment: @LisaBertash No, it means "art for the sake of art" instead. The word "art" is in there twice. Please see the accepted answer for details and ask a follow-up question if you want further clarification.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### "Art for the Sake of Art"

This phrase, quite conveniently, uses the same word order in both English and Latin.

*Ars, artis (artium)* is a third-declension feminine noun. It can mean "art" in the sense of paintings and sculptures, but can also be more abstract, like the "art" of writing (i.e. the skill and experience required to be a good writer). *Ars* is the nominative "art", *artis* is the genitive "of art".

Ex: *Ars Amātōria*, "The Art of Love", a poem by Ovid.

*Grātiā* is one of the very very few prepositions taking the genitive case, meaning "for the sake of". It started out as the ablative singular of the noun *grātia* (with short *a*), which originally meant "sake". But just like in English, the noun became uncommon except in the fixed expression "for the sake of..."; *grātia* came to mean "thanks" instead, and that's the meaning it has in the Romance languages (Italian *grazie*, Spanish *gracias*, etc). So *grātiā* was re-analyzed as a preposition.

Ex: *exemplī grātiā* (e.g.), "for the sake of example".

So *ars* is nominative singular "art", *grātiā* is a preposition "for the sake", and *artis* is genitive singular "of art".

Answer (score 2):

The ablatives causā and grātiā (for the sake of) are used with a Genitive preceding, or with a pronoun in agreement. (Allen and Greenough, 404 c).

http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/ablative-cause

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for the answer! If you register your account, you get some privileges already based on the reputation earned from this answer, allowing you to use the site more freely.