# Translation into Latin: "for the love of music"

Tags: motto, english-to-latin-translation

I am looking for a name for my newly-formed classical music studio, and I thought a Latin translation or equivalent of "for the love of music" may sound elegant. Would someone be willing to translate this? Or perhaps you have suggestions for other appropriate phrases?

Answer (score 7):

I suggest ***pro amore musicae***.
The phrase *amor musicae* means "love of music", where the music can be understood either objectively (music is loved) or subjectively (music loves).
The preposition *pro* requires ablative, whence the form *amore*.
This preposition is a common choice for "for the benefit of", as in *pro patria*, "for fatherland".

You might also want to take a look at [this question about the phrase *ars gratia artis*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1895/79).
If something like that sounds more appropriate, leave a comment below, and perhaps I or someone else can give a new suggestion.